# Ускорить добавление новой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

1. Получаем данные с сервера
2. Парсим
3. Результат парсинга добавляем в виде новой строки в `dataframe`

Код:

```
def __updateDB(self):

try:
    while True:
        # получаем результат
        result = self.__client_HTTP.query(
            symbol=symbol,

        )

            # парсим запрос
            for item in result['result']:
                dfTemp.loc[item['start']] = [item['open'], candle['buds']]


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Суть проблемы:

в результате запроса примерно 200 `item`, так вот, когда начинается добавление в `dateframe` - начинаются страшные лаги, 200 `item` добавляются в `timeframe` 11с !!! С чем это связано и как нужно добавлять корректно, чтобы все эта операция происходила быстро.

Я предполагаю, могу ошибаться, что когда я вызываю операцию добавления в `dataframe`:

> dfTemp.loc[item['start']] = [item['open'], candle['buds']]

создается копия оригинального `dataframe` с новой добавленной строкой и затем новый `dataframe` заменяет старый.

Важное уточнение!!! изначально `dataframe`, до добавления новой строки, уже имеет 1,5млн+ элементов

Что я пробовал:

1. Метод `append` - работает быстрее, примерно 2 сек на 200 элементов, но все же многовото
2. Создать временный пустой `dataframe` и туда добавить все строки из запроса, а затем приклеить к основному `dataframe`, работает очень быстро, на 200 элементов тратит примерно 50мс. Но что будет когда этот же `dataframe` будет иметь в себе 500к элементов и более, снова сработает принцип - чем больше элементов в `dataframe` тем дольше будет добавлять новая строка

Comment: 1. Как выглядят исходные данные? 2. Просто добавлять или же заменять старые данные? 3. Как должен выглядеть результат? 4. Куда потом выводится фрейм (если в БД, то проще сразу сохранять в БД без промежуточного фрейма)?

Comment: Да, лучше накапливать данные в списках/словарях, после чего делать из них новый датафрейм, который потом соединять с основным датафреймом через `concat`. Ну, так всё устроено, датафреймы изначально не предназначены для быстрого добавления данных.

Comment: @Алексей Р, да там 4 столбца всего-то формата int16 и за место индекса я использую ID в формате int16, просто значений получается не малое количество, до 2млн примерно строк. Нужно просто добавлять новую строку в конец. датафрейм потом используется по назначению - собирается статистика

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower

Comment: @Duracell на мой взгляд, по вашему описанию задача выглядит так, что можно просто собирать все записи в БД, например, SQLite, а по мере необходимости читать через `pd.read_sql()` и анализировать статистику. Необходимости склеивать фреймы в этом случае нет

Comment: @Алексей Р изначально так и было, но это очень дорого по времени, например считать 1,5млн значений из БД за 11,5сек или считать 1,5млн значений из оптимизированного csv файла за 44мс., Таже проблема и на запись - но сохранить в формат csv чуть быстрее чем сохранить в БД

Comment: @Duracell Хм, странно, что так долго данные из БД читаются. Это само чтение тормозит (индексов не хватает для быстрой выборки?) или преобразование данных в типы питона столько времени отнимает?

Comment: @CrazyElf, БД была mysql, с чем связано так и не понял, пробовал читать как из pd, так и напрямую через mysql'ский коннектор как в документации. Думаю дело было в формате колонок возможно, хотя я там задавал такие же типы данных как и у колонок scv. Еще один гвоздь в крышку гроба mysql - это то, что есть библиотека, забыл как называется, которая позволяет считать csv несколькими потоками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот я даже за вас небольшой эксперимент проделал. Суть в том, что скорость работы `pd.concat` не прямо пропорциональна размеру датафрейма. Основные затраты времени идут на создание нового датафрейма **почти независимо от его размера**. Именно поэтому лучше делать объединение одной операцией как можно реже, и ни в коем случае не делать это часто и в цикле.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

n, k, z = 1_500_000, 20, 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n, k))
x = range(7)
y = []
for i in x:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**i, k))
    r = 0
    for j in range(z):
        t = timer()
        df2 = pd.concat([df, df1])
        r += timer() - t
    y.append(r/z)
sns.lineplot(x=[10**i for i in x], y=y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.title('Зависимость времени присоединения от размера')
plt.xlabel('Размер присоединяемого датафрейма')
plt.ylabel('Время в секундах')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание - шкала размера логарифмическая.

График получается довольно разный на промежуточных значениях с каждым запуском не смотря на усреднение времени, которое я делаю, но основной вывод всё-равно такой: разница по времени между добавлением датафрейма из одной строки и из миллиона строк - всего в 2 раза (!!!). Именно поэтому выгодно накапливать данные в обычных объектах питона (например, в списках), а потом делать из них единоразово датафрейм и добавлять их в исходный датафрейм через `pd.concat`.

Если же такой сценарий работы вам не подходит и вам нужно очень быстро добавлять именно одиночные строки данных, то, как отметил в комментарии
Алексей Р, вам лучше использовать для этого базу данных. БД для такого сценария отлично подходят. Датафреймы же в основном предназначены для **анализа** данных, а не для их хранения и обновления.

Comment: спасибо за потраченное время, но вы зря его потратили))) ваш комментарий, как человека с большим опытом для меня авторитетен (пока я сеньером не стал-) ), поэтому я уже сделал как вы и советовали ранее, тем более я прочитал статью, которую приложил @Сергей Кох. На всякий случай опубликую мой вариант ответа, с вашими советами, вдруг кому пригодиться

Comment: @Duracell Да мне всегда прикольно какие-нибудь гипотезы проверить, повертеть данные, графики нарисовать, так что всё не зря ))

Answer (score 0):

На основе советов умных людей выше, пришел к выводу, что один из лучших вариантов для моей ситуации таков:

1. Делаем запрос `API`
2. Получаем ответ
3. Создаем пустой временный `dataframe` с нужными колонками
4. Парсим и одновременно суем в пустой `dataframe` нужные данные, в моем случае в виде новой строки
5. Далее конкатенируем временный `dataframe` с основным
6. Удаляем временный `dataframe` и снова  создаем пустой `dataframe` с нужными колонками
7. далее все повторяется до тех пор, пока не остановим цикл выборки

В коде будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
def __updateDB(self):

try:
    tempDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open', 'buds'])
    while True:
        # получаем результат
        result = self.__client_HTTP.query(
            symbol=symbol,

        )

            # парсим запрос
            for item in result['result']:
                tempDF.loc[item['start']] = [item['open'], candle['buds']]

             self.df = pd.concat([self.df, tempDf])
             def tempDf
             tempDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open', 'buds'])


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Что происходит при добавлении строки в уже заполненный большой `dataframe` наглядно показал @CrazyElf, так же советую прочитать инфу, по похожей теме, которую предложил @Сергей Кох